# Can't edit CSS in developer tools - bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

It's near impossible to live edit my CSS in Chrome developer tools. The problem is just on [this site](http://ecestudents.com/), not anywhere else on the web.

Trying to add a new rule or edit existing ones is almost impossible - it seems like the 'styles' tab keeps 'refreshing'. Basically, the rules keep flashing, not letting me edit them. Check it out for yourself!

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: I have no issues whatsoever editing the styles via Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug (in Firefox).

Comment: @Jona I have this exact same problem. Did you figure out what was causing it?